# Showing something is a projective $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

Would appreciate any help on this problem

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1, let $r_1,...,r_n\in R$ satisfy
>   $R = Rr_1+\ldots+Rr_n$.  If $M = \{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in R^n|a_1r_1+\ldots a_nr_n = 0\}$, show that $M$ is a projective $R$
>   module.

My ideas for this is to use the fact that the set $\{r_i-r_{i+1}\}$ generates $M$ and to somehow use the fact that a projective module is projective if it is the direct summand of a free module.  That seems to be the simplest way to go about it.  I'm not sure how to incorporate the fact that $R = Rr_1+\ldots+Rr_n$

[Old Qual Exam May 1996](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Pre_2012_papers/Algebra_Pre_2011.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Take $b=(b_1, \ldots, b_n)$ such that $\sum b_i r_i=1$ and show that 
$M\oplus R\cdot b = R^n$